# Fatal error: Call to undefined method TwitterOAuth::request()

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once 'twitteroauth.php';
```

I define my consumer key, consumer secret, oauth key and oauth secret.

```
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "my consumer key");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "my consumer secret");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "my oauth token");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "my oauth secret");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN,     OAUTH_SECRET);

// https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show
// Get User details

$user_id = 123456789; // user id can be fetched and stored from step 2.
$user_name = 'xxxx'; // screen name can be fetched and stored from step 2.

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

my browser show me => Fatal error: Call to undefined method TwitterOAuth::request()
but I could not understand where is the error.

```
$connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/users/show'), array('screen_name' =>     $user_name));

print '<pre>'; 
$decode_response = json_decode($code);
print_r($decode_response);
// It gives you - id, name, screen name, location, description, url, 
// followers count, following count, latest status, etc.
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the library right.

`$connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/users/show'), array('screen_name' =>     $user_name));`

I'm unsure where you got this from. Try:

`$connection->get('users/show', array('screen_name' => $user_name));`